# Wordpress image size medium shows different sizes

Tags: php, wordpress

Thanks for looking here and trying to provide some useful answer. Recently I have downloaded the plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/olevmedia-shortcodes/ and it works really fine. But when trying to use the short-code for "Recent Post" i'm facing image-sizing related issue that you see on the image attached below:

[image]

It looks really ugly. I opened a code and found the small piece of code for this function:

```
$out .= '<div class="omsc-recent-posts-title"><h3><a href="'. get_permalink() .'">'. get_the_title() .'</a></h3></div>';

                if( $thumbnail && has_post_thumbnail() ) {

                    $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), apply_filters('omsc_sc_recent_posts_img_size', 'medium'));
                    if($img) {
                        $img_html=apply_filters('omsc_sc_recent_posts_img', '<a href="'. get_permalink() .'"><img src="'.$img[0].'" alt="'.esc_attr($post->post_title).'" /></a>', array(
                            'img_src' => $img[0],
                            'link' => get_permalink(),
                            'alt' => $post->post_title,
                        ));
                        $out.='<div class="omsc-recent-posts-thumb">'.$img_html.'</a></div>';
                    }
                }
```

Then I look on the image size and it says:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), apply_filters('omsc_sc_recent_posts_img_size', 'medium'));
```

Checking through FireBug For some posts the "Medium" size is set to 222x221, for others 300x300 and for the rest 222x167

All I want to do is to make all thumbnails having the same size. So, I created this piece of code for my theme's function.php file:

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
add_image_size( 'custom-recpost-thumb', 222, 221,true ); 
}
```

and then for the plugin php file I made a call to the function in this way:

```
$img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), apply_filters('omsc_sc_recent_posts_img_size', 'custom-recpost-thumb'));
```

I see the same. Absolutely no changes has been made. What I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem as I can see it is that the pictures you upload is not the same dimensions so it will fit your width and make the height auto there are pretty much two ways you can get around this 1. fix your pictures before you upload or fit it with css no.2= make your box that holds your img the width and height that you want and make it overflow hidden then take your image and say it have to be the same height as the box and the width have to be auto the reason for this that most pictures is made as a landscape so in that way your pictures can fit.. for the record it is not a pretty way to do it and I would recommend fixing you pictures before you upload them

Comment: Hey Anker. Actually the second method you mentioned I have already triend and that's why I thought CSS wouldn't work. Now let me try the first through CSS. I won't be able to re-upload all images.

Comment: Solved :) Thank you. I thought PHP function of sizing would solve the problem without CSS manipulations. Learned something new.

Comment: Nice that you got it working. Just remember that depending on what dimensions your pictures have it can get out of shape again if its to much off. That you can fix by setting height of the picture over the height of the box but like I said it is not a pretty way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Different sizes of original images will create differently sized "medium" images.  This is because the medium settings in WordPress are there to accommodate images of different sizes. In general, those pixel settings provide reasonably good looking medium sized images for any size original image.  I suspect WordPress is overriding your function call to show "the best" image it can, based on its algorithms and image optimization.

Even with the coding options for WordPress.org, there are still some universal settings that WP will employ to create "good" websites. Maybe it's a reputation thing, maybe it's another example of technology organizations telling users what is best for them.

In any case, I agree with Anker that optimizing your images before you upload them is a better solution.  It will give you more control, and improve the chance that WP will display your images as you want.

Comment: The detail you have mentioned I didn't know. I will take into account this recommendation. I always try to upload original images, through Nikon and maybe I should adjust them ?

Comment: I don't know if Nikon does any image optimization, but it does sound like they do not resize images.  Maybe give it a try on 3 images and see if that works for you.